# SpringBoot @RestController more then one @Transactional methods

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

every one!
Configuration:
1. Spring Boot: Web, JPA, H2

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BankApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BankApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

BankAccountDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class BankAccountDaoImpl implements BankAccountDao {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public void saveBankAccount(BankAccount bankAccount) {
    Session currentSession = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();

    currentSession.save(bankAccount);
}

@Override
public BankAccount getBankAccount(int id) {
    Session currentSession = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();

    BankAccount bankAccount = currentSession.get(BankAccount.class, id);

    return bankAccount;
}
}
```

ClientAccountDaoImp:

```
@Repository
public class ClientAccountDaoImp implements ClientAccountDao{

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public void saveClientAccount(ClientAccount clientAccount) {
    Session currentSession = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();

    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(clientAccount);
}

@Override
public ClientAccount getClientAccount(int id) {
    Session currentSession = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();

    return currentSession.get(ClientAccount.class, id);
}
```

BankAccountServiceImpl and ClientAccountServiceImpl:
aitowired BankAccountDaoImpl and ClientAccountDaoImp

All method have @Transactional annotation:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveClientAccount(ClientAccount clientAccount) {
    clientAccountDao.saveClientAccount(clientAccount);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public ClientAccount getClientAccount(int id) {
    return clientAccountDao.getClientAccount(id);
}
```

I have @RestController:

```
   @GetMapping("/buy/{accountId}/sum/{money}")
   public ClientAccount chargeAccount(@PathVariable int accountId, 
   @PathVariable int money) {

    BankAccount bankAccount = bankAccountService.getBankAccount(1);
    int mn = bankAccount.getAmount() - money;
    bankAccount.setAmount(mn);
    bankAccountService.saveBankAccount(bankAccount);
    ClientAccount clientAccount = clientAccountService.getClientAccount(accountId);
    clientAccount.setAmount(money);

    clientAccountService.saveClientAccount(clientAccount);

    return clientAccount;
}
```

In the method 
`clientAccountService.saveClientAccount(clientAccount)`;
I have an exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate
>   proxy [com.sustavov.bank.entity.Client#1] with two open Sessions

If in Dao class I do `getCurrentSession()` except `openSession()`. 
I have an error:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in
>   progress

Comment: You are opening the two different sessions in `saveClientAccount` and `getClientAccount` and not **closing** them.  I think that is which causing **org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate proxy [com.sustavov.bank.entity.Client#1] with two open Sessions** since the client object is associated with different `session` Same applicable for `BackAccount` too.

Comment: use getCurrentSession